# Should I use nouveau driver or akmod-nvidia on my Fedora 23 system with GT630 graphics card?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

would akmod-nvidia driver work on my set up or Am I stuck using the default nouveau? if nouveau is good. would it work on playing dota 2 or csgo? thanks. This games was working fine when I was from windows 10 same graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Games will most likely not work with nouveau. Everything else, however should work.

If you do want games, akmod-nvidia is the way to go.